# trying to use pagination

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

So I am trying to use the gem will_paginate in rails 5 to paginate the post of my blog site. I added the gem to the gem file then did a bundle install it installed just fine. I then added this code to my post controller and when I try to go to my articles page I recieve the following error. I have no Idea what I am doing wrong and all examples I see say the same thing and error each time for me. Any suggestions? When I take the pagination out the page renders just fine. Safe to assume everything is up to date as well the gem, ruby, and rails

[image: post index.html.erb and post controller]

[image: The error I am getting]

Comment: Please edit your question and show the `index.html.erb file`.

Comment: Did you restart the server after installing? Looking at their docs, it should work fine with Rails 5. You seem to be using it correctly as well. You can also use a more ruby syntax for your order call. `.order(created_at: :desc)`

Comment: That was it restarting the server which I swore I tried before asking the question here. Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of your code looks fine in your index action you can also do something like this and do restart your `rails server`:

```
def index
  @posts = Post.all.order(created_at: :desc).paginate(page:  params[:page], per_page: 2)
end
```

Comment: restarting the server was the real answer. Which I thought I did already before posting the question here thank you so much!